# Using Jquery to dynamically add/delete table rows

Tags: jquery, attr

I am working on dynamically allowing a user to add or remove table rows which contain form fields.

there are two main issues I am having- which entail being able to use a selector to capture the second element of a table (in hopes of ignoring the header row)

and second working with jQuery and the disabled attribute. When calling it initially I cannot change the attribute there after with a js if statement.

my code is here for review: http://jsfiddle.net/Jcortes/BE5Lr/792/

If anyone could help it'd be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#DelBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
var count = 1;
//*******************************************************************    
$('#AddBtn').click(function() {
    //problem is below, the selector is not returning the other elements. (ex=second)
    $("table tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function() {
        $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) {
            return id + count;
        });
    }).end().appendTo("table");
    count++;
    if (count == 2) {
        $('#DelBtn').attr('disabled', '');
    }        
    if (count == 5) {
        $('#AddBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}); //end AddBtn Function
//*******************************************************************    
$('#DelBtn').click(function() {
    $("table tr:last").remove();
    count--;
    if (count == 1) {
        $('#DelBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#AddBtn').attr('disabled', '');
    }
}); //end DelBtn Function
//*******************************************************************    
}); //end DOM Ready
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I notice that the delete button doesn't become re-enabled, but what else?

Comment: I don't understand your first problem. What is wrong with your selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the `attr('disabled', '')` call fails i because you are using jQuery 1.7. jquery 1.7 now properly differentiates between attributes and properties. Disabled is a property. Use the [.prop() method](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead.

```
$('selector').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
$('selector').prop('disabled', '');
```

Ah, I see second problem now. You can use nth-child selector to get second row.

```
$('table tr:nth-child(2)').clone();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BE5Lr/793/

Comment: I think I get it now. You want a selector that will clone the second row because the first row are your column descriptors. You can use the nth-child selector to do this.